# Escaping the path when launching an application in JavaScript via an ActiveX control

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, activex

### Objective

I want to send a file path to a .NET COM component via JavaScript without having to escape it in JavaScript.

---

### Environment

- Windows 7 x64
- .NET 4.0

### What do we know?

- When you pass a path like `C:\temp` you get the following...

[image]

- When you pass a UNC path like `\\Server\Directory` you get the following...

[image]

- When you escape the path (e.g. `C:\\temp` or `\\\\Server\\Directory`) the value that is received is correct.

### What have I tried?

- I've tried using the `@` in front of the variable name when storing to a private field.
- I've tried to find somebody doing the same thing with my Google Fu, but haven't.

### Code

#### COM Component

```
[Guid("30307EE0-82D9-4917-B07C-D3AB185FEF13")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ILauncher
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void setDirectory(string location);

    [DispId(2)]
    void launch(string args, bool debug = false);
}

[Guid("F91A7E9F-2397-4DEC-BDAD-EBFC65CFCCB2")]
[ProgId("MyActiveXControl.MyControl")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ILauncher))]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Launcher : ILauncher
{
    private string _location;

    public void setDirectory(string location)
    {
        _location = location;
    }

    public void launch(string args, bool debug = false)
    {
        var programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(programFiles))
        {
            programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
        }

        var exe = string.Format(@"{0}\MyApp\MyApp.exe", programFiles);
        if (debug)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exe, "Target Path", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            MessageBox.Show(_location, "Drop Location", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exe, string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", args, _location));
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exe);
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        try
        {
            var p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            if (p == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The app could not be started, please try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Launch Control" onclick="launchControl();" />

        <script>
            function launchControl() {
                o = new ActiveXObject("MyActiveXControl.MyControl");
                o.setDirectory("C:\\temp");
                o.launch("test_args", true);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we found that we just needed to change the JavaScript because it can't be done later. By the time it gets to us we'd have to end up adding backslashes, but we wouldn't really be able to because we wouldn't know where one directory began and another ended.

Just modify the JavaScript.

So we worked with the powers that be and all is well.